# How to save date in sequelize insert raw query?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, timestamp, sequelize.js

I am using raw query in sequelize to save my data into the table. The database used is postgresql. The createdAt and updatedAt columns are throwing an error when I try to save my data into the database.

This is the code I have written:

```
const d = {
  'createdAt': new Date(),
  'updatedAt': new Date()
}
const query = `insert into "PRODUCT" ("createdAt", "updatedAt", "PRODUCT_ID", "USER_ID") values ('${d.createdAt}','${d.updatedAt}', 1, 1)`
let resp = await sequelize.query(query, {
raw: true,
type: 'INSERT',
})
```

When I use sequelize queries directly with this data, the row gets created but when I run the raw query it fails. This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: time zone "gmt+0530" not recognized
```

This is what is there in query:

```
insert into "PRODUCT" ("createdAt", "updatedAt", "PRODUCT_ID", "USER_ID") values ('Thu Apr 20 2023 01:43:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)','Thu Apr 20 2023 01:43:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 1, 1)
```

I want time to be in this format:

```
2023-04-19 12:21:10.684+05:30
```

Somehow when using sequelize queries directly, the time was getting added in the above format. When I print variable d, that also is coming in the above mentioned format. Only when running raw query, the data is as shown in query output. How do I go about this?

Comment: use `bind` option to pass parameters to the raw query and more importantly to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enter the current server time using a raw query, you can do it with a literal string using

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

so that would become either

```
const d = {
  'createdAt': sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
  'updatedAt': sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
}
const query = `insert into "PRODUCT" ("createdAt", "updatedAt", "PRODUCT_ID", "USER_ID") values ('${d.createdAt}','${d.updatedAt}', 1, 1)`
```

or, in case you still want a js date object in `d`:

```
const d = {
  'createdAt': new Date(),
  'updatedAt': new Date()
}; 
// d is now unused in this example, but d.createdAt is still usable in case you need it further down your code

const query = `insert into "PRODUCT" ("createdAt", "updatedAt", "PRODUCT_ID", "USER_ID") values ('${`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`}','${`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`}', 1, 1)`
```